Not able to run graalvm native image for a application which has spring boot 3 and loading secrets from AWS secret manager with spring cloud aws
My application has spring boot 3.1.7 and spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config enabled 2.4.4 version
shashankjain@shashank bifrost % java -version
java version "22" 2024-03-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 22+36.1 (build 22+36-jvmci-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 22+36.1 (build 22+36-jvmci-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

I am creating a native image with below command
mvn -Pnative native:compile -DskipTests -Daot.profiles=local_stage -Dspring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true

And running above created native image with command:
target/bifrost -Dspring.profiles.active=local_stage -Dspring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true

The above run command ends up doing nothing wheares when i remove -Dspring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true from command then native image ran fine but without loading the secrets from the AWS secret store.
target/bifrost -Dspring.profiles.active=local_stage

Please let me know how can I run my application which can also load secrets from AWS secret store.
I have tried running my native image with graalvm verions 17.0.10-graal, 22-graal and 23.ea.10-graal.
I have also tried upgrading spring boot from 3.1.7 to 3.3.0 but no luck.
